# Can one gives an immersion of an exotic sphere ?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Can one gives an immersion of an exotic sphere (John Milnor's exotic spheres) S^7 in an S^8(1)? (asking for some examples).Thanks!

Ps:Here "S^(R)"means n-sphere of radius R.

Comment: Such immersions certainly exist, but I don't know a place where one is written down.  This follows from the fact that the tangent bundle of an exotic sphere is trivial (see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/58131) and then an application of the Hirsch-Smale immersion theory, which implies that any parallelizable $n$-manifold can be immersed in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ (and hence in the $(n{+}1)$-sphere).

Comment: I don't understand why this has been marked as a duplicate.  The OP originally posted this question with 'exhaustive' instead of 'exotic', which was incorrect terminology.  Apparently, the OP posted again because the OP wasn't able to fix the original question.  Also, the claim that it 'already has an answer' seems to be wrong; at least the previous (incorrect) version does not have an answer (as of now).  If there is another equivalent question that does have an answer, then it would be helpful if one of the people who marked it as 'duplicate' would indicate where the answer is.